# loadGeoJson not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am using `.loadGeoJson` to load geojson data into a Google Maps API instance. I have used this previously but this time it is not loading any data and I am not sure why.

The previous code I have used is:

```
var localLayer = new google.maps.Data();
localLayer.loadGeoJson('JSON/local.geojson');
localLayer.setMap(map);
```

My current code looks like:

JavaScript:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 39.154743,
            lng: -77.240515
        },
        zoom: 10
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMap();
    var localLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    localLayer.loadGeoJson('json/Schools.geojson');
    localLayer.setMap(map);
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 3px black;
}
```

The file path is `json/Schools.geojson`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the geoJson-response also would be interesting

Comment: Is your GeoJson valid?  What does it look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [My gh-pages are here](http://alexdingis.github.io/hispanic-location-quotient/) and [my git hub repo is here](https://github.com/alexdingis/hispanic-location-quotient/tree/master).

Comment: The geojson in the current question was created from the same shapefile of census tracts as in the previous example that I know works, the only difference are a few attribute fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [Schools.geojson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexdingis/hispanic-location-quotient/master/json/Schools.geojson) contains invalid coordinates, for example:  `[1263179.3749040514, 541288.18736040592]`.  You could utilize 
[Data Layer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) to validate Geo JSON data. Once incorrect lat/lng values has been provided, [Data Layer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) returns `90` value for for latitude property of `google.maps.LatLng` object:

Add the following line:

```
schoolLayer.addListener('addfeature', validateData);
```

where

```
function validateData(o) {

   var validateCoordinates = function (items) {
        var validAll = items.every(function (item) {
            var latLngs = item.getArray();
            valid = latLngs.every(function (latLng) {
                return isValidLatLng(latLng);
            });
            return valid;
        });
        return validAll;
    };

    var f = o.feature;
    var geometry = f.getGeometry();
    if (geometry.getType() == "MultiPolygon") {
        var allCoords = geometry.getArray();
        allCoords.forEach(function(coords) {
            if (!validateCoordinates(coords.getArray())) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Geo JSON contains invalid lat/lng'; 
            }
        });
    } else {
        var coords = geometry.getArray();
        if (!validateCoordinates(coords)) {
             document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Geo JSON contains invalid lat/lng'; 
        }
    }
}



function isValidLatLng(latLng) {
    return latLng.lat() != 90;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHoYFzdzOYziBpRY61AX) that demonstrates how to validate Geo JSON.

Comment: As soon as I read the first line, I went back to ArcGIS and saw I still had the shapefile in Maryland State Plane. I then looked the two geojson files I had and saw the difference in the coordinates. For anyone else reading this, make sure your coordinate system is in **GCS_North_American_1983** before you convert into geojson.